# TypeORM insert basic master data (types, status,..) after creating the table

Tags: typescript, nestjs, typeorm

I have question for you. I am using NestJS and typeORM. I am trying to insert default values to tables after creating the tables. For example i have a priority table and i need to insert High/Medium/Low values. I tried everything from typeorm and nestJS documentation and I read related questions and answers from here. I could not do it yet.

```
import {getConnection} from "typeorm";

await getConnection()
    .createQueryBuilder()
    .insert()
    .into(User)
    .values([
        { firstName: "Timber", lastName: "Saw" }, 
        { firstName: "Phantom", lastName: "Lancer" }
     ])
    .execute();
```

I have found above code and i think the way is this. But i could not find in which file should i use this code chunk. If you help me i will be very happy. Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use **migrations** to keep your database up to date. They can be used not only to modify tables, but also to add default data. TypeORM has a [mechanism](https://typeorm.io/#/migrations) for doing this.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. In documentation i could not see any sample like my case. Do you have a working sample? or it will be a good article somewhere on the web.

Comment: [Here](https://medium.com/better-programming/typeorm-migrations-explained-fdb4f27cb1b3) is a good practical guide for using this technique. But there is a nuance. QueryRunner has no methods for inserting data into the database. I found a useful closed [issue](https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/2087) that says how to access QueryBuilder through a reference to the Entities Manager.

Answer (score 1):

I use migrations for this purpose. We can write static query or we can also load data from CSV and then save it in DB in a loop.

you can create an empty migration with `npx typeorm migration:create -n InsertMasterDataInDB`

and then you can use below query to insert data

`await queryRunner.manager.query(INSERT QUERY HERE IN SINGLE QUOTES);`

and then `npx typeorm migration:run`

Answer (score 0):

As mentioned above you can use migration
The ideal scenario though is to use seeders and populate the table with the data upon the successful migration

I recomend using **typeorm-seeding** package for this

Migration should contain only changes to the structure of the database. Try to isolate the db structure and actual data seeding as much as possible.