# How to Parse CSV in TypeORM and PostgreSQL

Tags: typescript, postgresql, typeorm, node.js-typeorm

I am trying to extract data from a csv and save it to my PostgreSQL database using TypeORM, how can I access the result inside the parse function(callback), I need it so I will able to save data on my csv? In my controller I have the following:

```
const fs = require('fs');

import { parse } from 'csv-parse';

class RoomsController {
  public RoomsService = new RoomsService();

 public uploadRoomsTemplate = async (req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    try {
      // eslint-disable-next-line no-var
      var myRes;
      const csvFilePath = req.file.path;
      const headers = [
        'ward',
        'hub',
        'room_size',
        'status',
      ];
      const fileContent = fs.readFileSync(csvFilePath, { encoding: 'utf8' });
      parse(
        fileContent,
        {
          delimiter: ',',
          columns: headers,
        },
        (error, result: RoomTemplate[]) => {
          myRes = result;
          if (error) {
            console.log(error);
          }
          console.log(result);
          return result;
        },
      );

      const createRoomData: Room = await this.RoomsService.uploadRoomTemplate(myRes);
      return createRoomData;
    } catch (error) {
      next(error);
    }
  };
}
```

in my service file, I have:

```
   public async uploadRoomTemplate(RoomData: CreateRoomDto): Promise<TgHubTemplate> {
    // if (isEmpty(RoomData)) throw new HttpException(400, 'RoomData is empty');

    const RoomRepository = getRepository(this.RoomTemplate);
    const findRoomTemplate: RoomTemplate = await RoomRepository.findOne({ where: { id: RoomData.id } });
    if (findRoomTemplate) throw new HttpException(409, `${RoomData.id} already exists`);

    const createdRoomTemplate: RoomTemplate = await RoomRepository.save({ ...RoomData });

    return createdTgHubTemplate;
```

Comment: here an asnwer that can help you: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64203055/typeorm-insert-basic-master-data-types-status-after-creating-the-table

Comment: or this one: https://github.com/typeorm/typeorm/issues/3483